# Creating QR code to redirect phone's contacts

Tags: react-native, qr-code, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to build a REACT NATIVE application to generate a QR code in the application and save some contact information in that QR code.

And if another phone scans that QR is generated before QR will redirect the phone to contacs addition page.

Is it possible, and if is how can i manage that?

I already think that somehow we can create a vcf file into a qr code reader, is it possible? Or is there any better solution to my problem?

fyi: [Vcard](https://www.qr-code-generator.com/solutions/vcard-qr-code/)

fyi2: [React native QR code package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

First you have to generate the vcard, check this library:  [react-native-vcards](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vcards)

then you should put `const qrValue = contact.getFormattedString()` in the `<QRCode value={qrValue} ...>` using the library you shared